# What is this date filter accomplishing in this SQL query?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm reviewing a long query for work and I'm trying to determine what this date filter is doing. I generally understand that's it's looking at data going back 29 hours, but I'm specifically wondering about the time portions that have "H:00". What is portion of the query doing? What's the difference in this and putting something like "'%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s'?

```
AND (s.start_date >= DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00'),INTERVAL -29 HOUR)

AND s.start_date < DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00'),INTERVAL -29 HOUR),INTERVAL 30 HOUR))
```

(I am using SQL Pro, Mariadb)

Comment: `%H` is simply a two-digit [hour format](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date_format/). You can simply run that portion of the query by doing: `SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00'),INTERVAL -29 HOUR)
` to see the result.

Comment: But what is the "00" portion doing? I have thousands of results that are all in the above date format but the time on every result is midnight. Like this..."2020-01-01 00:00:00". So I'm trying to determine what the "00" is doing. Is it creating a midnight timestamp on every result? Or is it saying 'take the two digit now() hour, and subtract 29 hours from that hour'?